# This JavaScript code will not execute properly if the alert is commented out.

Tags: javascript, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am trying to write a simple JavaScript page timer for a web app. The timer will record the time at the press of a button (as the user enters the page) and record the time again at the press of a button (when the user leaves the page) The difference of the 2 times will give the time the user spent on the page. If they stayed on the page for more than 2 seconds the number of seconds will be recorded to the local database on the hand held.

The problem I am having is that the following code will not work if the alert in the starttime function is commented out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.m1-root').click(function () {
      //simulate the pagetransition events in mobile framework
        pagename= $(this).attr('id'); 
        starttime();
    //alert("You are leaving\n" + pagename + "\n you were here for \n" + time.toFixed(0) + " seconds"); // This alert will fire but only record the proper time if the next alert is fired
    });
}); 

function starttime()
{
//create a starting timestamp, number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970
start = new Date().getTime();
//alert(+ start); // if this alert is commented out the time is not started
    pagetime();
}

function pagetime(pagename){
time = (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000;
//alert("you have been on " + pagename + " for \n" + time.toFixed(0) + " seconds");
//before we transition, log previous page and time
//if time is greater than 3 seconds we log it (I changed it to -1 so that I would see any figure while testing)
if (time >-1)
{
//DataBase update
db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO CBNapp_Usage VALUES (time)',function(tx,result) {},function(tx,Error) {});});   
//alert("You spent " + time.toFixed(0) + " seconds on " + pagename);
}
}
```

I have looked on SO and the web and have come across similar situations but I can not seem to get any of those ideas to work here. I understand that this may be a timing problem and have tried a setTimeout  or return true to delay things but it does not work.

Could someone please take a look at the code and suggest how I might be able to get it to work properly?

This is my first from scratch JS. Please provide specific examples so I can follow them. The database is also not recording but I will work on that later. If you have any other specific suggestions as to how to improve this I would welcome them.

Thanks for taking the time to help.

Ted

Comment: I'm a little confused by your sample. You run the same code both times the button is clicked... so you're just going to overwrite your start value and then *immediately* record the end-time, which will therefore be a few milliseconds at best.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting a time when they enter Which I am trying to save as a variable, start. I am again getting a time when they leave the page and calculating the difference to get the time the user was on the page. It works well when the alert is not commented. How should I do it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got all your code inside the button click handler. It only appears to be working when you have the alert, because the alert creates the appearance of delay.

You need to put starttime() outside of the click handler, and it shouldn't be calling pagetime().

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    starttime(); // this will run as soon as the page loads
    $('div.m1-root').click(function () {
        pagetime();
        // leave the page
    });
});

function starttime() {
    start = new Date().getTime(); // start is global
}

function pagetime() {
    var time = (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000;
    // do something with time, like logging it to your db
}
```

Comment: THANKS! That solved the alert problem! I had to make a few changes for your code to suit my purposes exactly but you got me unstuck!

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
  pagename= $(this).attr('id');
```

The above will create a global variable called *pagename* when the code executes. If you mean to do that, you should declare it in the appropriate scope (i.e. global). However, it is generally considered better to store it as an object property or in a closure and avoid unnecessary global variables.

Also, it is very much more efficient to use:

```
  pagename = this.id;
```

The line:

```
  starttime();
```

calls the *starttime* function...

```
function starttime() {
  //create a starting timestamp...
  start = new Date().getTime();
```

Again, make sure you declare variables in an appropriate scope or use some other strategy for sharing values. Also, you can leave *start* as a Date object (i.e. don't call *getTime*).

```
  //alert(+ start); // if this alert is commented out the time is not started
```

That usually  indicates that the pause created by the alter is "fixing" your issue, so it has something to do with timing.

```
  pagetime();
```

Now it calls *pagetime*.

```
function pagetime(pagename) {
  time = (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000;
```

Again an implicit global.

Here you call *pagetime* immediately after setting *start*, likely the clock hasn't moved. In some browsers, the timer resolution is about 15ms so unless the CPU is **very** busy doing something else or you chance on that 15ms boundary (extremely unlikely) then *new Date()* will have exactly the same value as *start*.

You can also do the assignment as:

```
  time = (new Date()) - start;
```

But *time* will almost certainly be zero, bhamlin has the fix for that.

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented most of your clean up. (I could not get the last one to work) I obviously have much more studying to do. I understand the difference between local and global variables but I seem to have a mental block about how to get local variables to be used from one function to another. I'll keep trying :-)